# Android Studio latest version could not find method compile for arguments directory libs

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio

I have pasted my build.gradle codes in this question, please suggest what to do.

Error message:

> Could not find method compile() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Configuration:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

ext {

    supportVersion='27.1.1'
}

android {

   compileSdkVersion 28

   defaultConfig {

       applicationId "com.eassycars.www.dlservices"

       minSdkVersion 17

       targetSdkVersion 28

       versionCode 1

       versionName "1.0"

       testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

   }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        configure(':app') {
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build.gradle:4.8.1'
            compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
            compile
            testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
            // google & support
            implementation "com.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler :$supportVersion"
            implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportVersion"
            implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportVersion"
            implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportVersion"
            implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportVersion"
            implementation "com.android.support:palette-v7:$supportVersion"
            implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:$supportVersion"
            implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportVersion"
            implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.0.4'
            // utils
            implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
            annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0'
            implementation 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.7'
            implementation 'com.github.Commit451:bypasses:1.0.4'
            implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.0'
            annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.0'
            implementation 'com.drewnoakes:metadata-extractor:2.9.1'
            implementation 'com.orhanobut:hawk:2.0.1'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
            compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
        }}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you got a "compile" statement under "compile fileTree" with empty library.
second change "compile fileTree" to "implementation fileTree"

Comment: I Have Done It Whatever Your Said But i Am Still gettting error and error message is : - Could not find method implementation() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: Now What To Do If I Want to Fix This Please tell me

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project's build.gradle and check it's version under dependencies.

[check project's build.gradle version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwxrS.png)

If you're using a version of Gradle lower than 4.1 then use this

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
         maven {
             url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
```